# How can I calculate the time function T(n) of the following code?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, computer-science, complexity-theory

```
x=0;
for(int i=1 ; i<=n ; i++){
    for(int j=1 ; j<=n ; j++){
        x++;
        n--;
    }
}
```

By testing the code, the nested FOR loop recurs ⌈n/2⌉ times per steps of the first For loop.

But I don't know how to formulate these rules with sigmas. I would really appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: Hello! This question may be better suited for [CS StackExchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Why the nested for loop recurs ⌈n/2⌉ times per steps of the first for loop if they both run until they reach n?

Comment: @Eloy Pérez Torres - Because the variable n decrements at each step of the first loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can express T(n) as T(n-2)+1, i.e. T(n)=T(n-2)+1 Or its expected time complexity is O(n/2) => O(n).

Edit:  T(n-2)+1 expression is evaluated as you can see if you increase n-2 by 2 means when n-2 became n, the number of times the loop will be executed is the 1 + number of time loop executed for n-2. 1 is because you are incrementing j and decrementing n simultaneously. it is exactly the same as incrementing j by 2.

Comment: How did you get `T(n-2)+1`?

Comment: I don't think that this would be the right answer because we're not decrementing i and n simultaneously. Every step of the outer loop is dividing n by 2.

Answer (score 1):

Let's compute the exact value of `x`.

TL;DR: `x(N) = N-[N/2^i+1]`, where `i` is the lowest number, satisfying the condition: `(i+1) 2^i > N`. As *Mariano Demarchi* said, `T(N)=O(N)`.

---

First we will check how variables change after each inner loop. Let we have `(n, i, x)` values between 2 and 3 lines in code (before the inner loop):

- How many iterations will happens? Each iteration increases `j` and decreases `n`, so the distance between them decreases by two. Start distance is `n-1`, and final, after the loop, is `0` (if `n` is odd) or `-1` (if `n` is even). Thus if `n=2k`, the answer is `k`, otherwise `k+1`. So, the inner loop makes `[(n+1)/2] = d` iterations.
- Thus `x` will increase by `d`, `n` becomes `n-d` and `i` becomes `i+1`.
- `(n, i, x) -> (n-d, i+1, x+d)` or equal `([n/2], i+1, x + [(n+1)/2])`

---

Now concentrate on values of `n` and `i` variables in the big loop:

- They changes like that: `(n, i) -> ([n/2], i+1)`
- The stop-condition is `[N/2^i] < i+1`, which is equals to `(i+1)*2^i > N`. Of course, we need minimal `i`, satisfying the condition.

So, `i` is the first number satisfying the condition and we **DO NOT SUM** further:

```
    x = [(N+1)/2] + [([N/2]+1)/2] + [([N/2^2]+1)/2] + ... + [([N/2^i-1]+1)/2]
```

By the number theory magic (not related on this question) this series is equals to `N (1-1/2^i+1)`. Particularly, if `N` is a power of 2 minus 1, we can see it easily.

So, this code returns exactly the same value in `O(log(N))` time.

```
// finding i
unsigned long long i = 0;
while ((i + 1) * (1ll << i) < n)
    ++i;

// finding x
x = n - (n >> (i + 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the inner loop, given that n decrements at the same time that j increments, n is going to be lower than j at the middle of the difference between both initial values, that is `(n-1)/2`.
That's why your tests show that the inner loop runs `⌈n/2⌉` times per each iteration of the outer loop.

Then the outer loop is going to stop when for the i that satisfies this equality `n/2^i = i-1`. This affects the outer loop stopping condition.

```
T(n)
```

=

```
n/2 + T(n/2)
```

=

```
n/2 + n/4 + T(n/4)
```

=

```
n (1/2 + 1/4 + ... + 1/(2^i))
```

This series converges to `n` so that algorithm is `O(n)`.